# Using PrincipalPermissionAttribute with Custom role provider

Tags: wcf-security, roleprovider

I'm working on a new security infrastracture for my organization. Since we develop systems for the inside organization use I'd like to use Windows Authentication, but for the authorization we manage a separate Oracle DB (for historical reasons). My idea was to use `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` defining

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
```

in Global::Application_Start
and

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager **defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider"**
      enabled="true"
      cacheRolesInCookie="true"
      cookieName=".ASPROLES"
      cookieTimeout="30"
      cookiePath="/"
      cookieRequireSSL="false"
      cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
      cookieProtection="All" >
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add
          name="MyRoleProvider"
          type="WcfServiceLibrary1.MyRoleProvider"
          connectionStringName="Service1"
          applicationName="InfraTest"
          writeExceptionsToEventLog="true" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport **clientCredentialType="Windows"** />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="WcfAuthenticationTest" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint"
          contract="WcfService1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WcfAuthentication"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceAuthorization **principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"**/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

in my Web.config using my **custom role provider** that should access the Oracle DB to check the role. But I can not make it work. Is there any way to make the `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` work in this way or may be the entire concept is wrong? I thought of implementing my custom `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` but it is not that simple so I prefer not to do it
Does anybody have any idea of the issue? I'll be glad to get some answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that I've learned lately. First af all my concept was right, I can use PrinciplePermissionAttribute with costom role provider, the second is that I was totaly confused with the web.config tags.  tag is used for the asp .net settings,  while  is used for WCF settings. So a liitle bit configuration solved the entire problem. Here is the right configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES"
      defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="Service1" applicationName="InfraTest"
          writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" name="MyRoleProvider" type="SecLib.MyRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfRoleProviderTestService.Service1"
               behaviorConfiguration="BasicHttpServiceBehavior" >
        <endpoint name="BasicHttpEndpoint"
                  contract="WcfRoleProviderTestService.IService1"
                  address="WcfAuthenticationTest"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WcfRoleProviderTestService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BasicHttpServiceBehavior">
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"
            roleProviderName="MyRoleProvider" impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not include `impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true"` unless you need impersonation

Comment: The problem is that I do need the impersonation in order to check the client permission